# Magento: Media files returns No input file specified

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I'm working on a magento eCommerce solution, and i'm currently experiencing a problem, where I can't access the files within the /media directory from php. I have googled it a lot, but haven't find an solution yet.

My .htaccess file in the /media directory looks like this:

```
    Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

# AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
# Options -ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php
    RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Apache rewrites. However, I believe that your rewrite conditions are incomplete. Here are the ones I used for most Magento sites:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Another possibility is that file permissions aren't right for the media directory. You can fix them for the entire application with the following commands, run from command line within your root Magento directory:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;
chmod o+w var var/.htaccess app/etc
chmod 550 pear
chmod -R o+w media
```

Comment: The problem was caused by:
Options -ExecCGI and Options All -Indexes
It works now. Thanks for the input! I overlooked the line with Options All -Indexes, which I realized immediately after your post. Thanks!